# Django on click get main window's url

Tags: python, django

[image]

I want to get the main window's url(ie. 127.0.01:8000/add_person/N/...) on clicking the delete button in views.py so that on delete it redirects to the same page

**request.path** gives the delete button's url (i.e delete_person/id)

```
def delete_person(request, id):  
    person = Person.objects.get(id=id)  
    person.delete()  
    return redirect('/add_person/' + pname + "/" + ptype)
```

Comment: What is pname and ptype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of the referring page is usually (depending on the server config) available as HTTP_REFERER in the request META data:

```py
def delete_person(request, id):  
    referrer = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

([Here’s a working example](https://repl.it/@teroyks/Django-HTTPREFERER#mysite/views.py))

Answer (score 0):

You can get the relative path of an incoming request via **`request.META`**:

```
def delete_person(request, id):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=id)  
    person.delete()  
    current_path = request.META.PAGE_INFO
    ...
```